# Find $c$ such that $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{\sqrt 8}}^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 8}} \frac{ \ln(c - u)}{(1- u^4)^{1/4}} du = 0.$

Tags: calculus, optimization, definite-integrals

Find the unique positive real $c$ such that $\int_{\frac{-\pi}{\sqrt 8}}^{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt 8}} \frac{ \ln(c - u)}{(1- u^4)^{1/4}} du = 0.$

You may use $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{(1-u^4)^{1/4}} = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt 2}$.